# Remote Connection using Management Scope?

Tags: c#, networking, system, remote-access

Am trying to connect the remote system from my local machine with the help of Management Scope.

**What i tried is:**

My code as follows,

```
 ConnectionOptions con= new ConnectionOptions();
 con.Username = strUsername;
 con.Password = strPassword;
 con.Impersonation = ImpersonationLevel.Impersonate;
 con.EnablePrivileges = true;
 ManagementScope ManagementScope1 = new ManagementScope(string.Format("\\\\{0}\\root\\cimv2", strIP), con);
 ManagementScope1.Connect();
```

**My Problem is:**

With the preceding code, I can connect with remote system when It has some username and password.(strUsername = "User", strPassword="Welcome")

**But in case of blank password (strUsername = "User", strPassword = "") , am getting the error named as "Access is Denied". The connecting remote system has no protection from the password**.

Remote system user gave all sorts of permission to access the machine, but still am facing with this strange issue.

please let me know where am going wrong. Any help is much appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: have you tried using your application as admin?

Comment: Yes am working and running my application as admin only.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use currently logged user to access remote WMI, you have to pass null as Username.

> null if the connection will use the currently logged-on user; otherwise, a string representing the user name. The default value is null.

Source: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/system.management.connectionoptions.username(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Local Machine and remote machine are connected successfully through WMI. And username is available for Remote machine rather password is blank. Also i passed as null, still am facing the same issue.